# How to get the average duration for each category having films using stream API java

Tags: dictionary, java-stream, average

I have a class Film with the following fields

```
      String name;
      double duration;
      Collection<String> categories;
```

My task is to return a `Map<String, Double>` that represents the average duration by category.
I have to use Stream API of Java.

My idea is to form entries of `String` for the category and `List<Double>` where the elements are the different durations, and then to use stream api method map and map it to map of string and average. But I am not sure how to do it. Can someone help me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [three-argument form of `Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) with a downstream [`Collectors.averagingDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)) collector to do it in a single pass. Java 17 example (Including using `Map.Entry` to emulate a 2-element tuple or pair class):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Demo {
    private record Film(String name, double duration,
                        Collection<String> categories) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var films = List.of(new Film("The Terminator", 1.783,
                                     List.of("Sci-Fi", "Action")),
                            new Film("Alien", 1.95,
                                     List.of("Sci-Fi", "Horror")));

        Map<String,Double> avgDurations = films.stream()
            // Get a stream of (Category, Duration) pairs
            .flatMap(film ->
                     film.categories().stream()
                     .map(cat -> Map.entry(cat, film.duration())))
            // Group by Category and calculate the average of each
            // group's Durations in a TreeMap
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                           TreeMap::new,
                                           Collectors.averagingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)));

        System.out.println(avgDurations);
    }
}
```

When compiled and run, prints out

```
{Action=1.783, Horror=1.95, Sci-Fi=1.8664999999999998}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I have a question, I think it would be ok to use HashMap::new instead of TreeMap::new, am I correct?

Comment: @vanderwaal If you don't care about order, sure.

Comment: yes, I don't care about it, thank you very much!